# nltk.download('punkt') giving output as false

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, data-science, nltk

Here is my code:

```
df['num_words'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x:len(nltk.word_tokenize(x)))
```

which gives me the following error:

```
Resource punkt not found.
Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:
   
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.download('punkt')
  
For more information see: https://www.nltk.org/data.html

Attempted to load tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle
```

Then I tried to install `nltk` and download the file `'punkt'` using `nltk.download('punkt')`.
But I am getting this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8UM2.png).

I tried some alternative codes like:

```
import nltk
import ssl

try:
    _create_unverified_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
except AttributeError:
    pass
else:
    ssl._create_default_https_context = _create_unverified_https_context

nltk.download()
```

Also tried changing the networks as at some places I found it is saying server issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to launch the jupyter notebooks session as administrator (open the command or anaconda prompt as administrator).

The last option would be to download the corpus manually. You may find [this](https://thinkinfi.com/how-to-download-nltk-corpus-manually/), helpful in your case.